# Best way to store a big list linked to client in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my web app, a database where each client has an average of 1K - 100K lines of  *data*. I thought at first to store every single line as one row connected to the user but another thought was to store all these in a single column which would have a column with userid. Both of these ideas seemed good but which one would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Simple - database are for rows :)

Comment: sql server, my bad!

Comment: What does your 'data' look like? Is it free text?

Comment: yes, its free text but a line shouldn't be longer then 2 - 3 average sentences